# OS based shebang

Tags: shell, operating-system, porting

I have lot of scripts written in `Solaris` which uses shebangs like these:

```
/usr/bin/sh
/usr/bin/ksh
```

I am porting the code to Linux which has the interpreters placed in `/bin`.

Is there any way to modify the shebang so that the scripts work in both `Solaris` and `Linux`

I hope we cannot do a OS check for the shebang like below:

```
if [ $os == "Linux" ]
then
    #!/bin/sh
else
    #!/usr/bin/sh
fi
```

Is it fine to add links in Linux like below:

```
/usr/bin/sh --> /bin/sh
```

Comment: This is one of the motivating factors behind `env` - you could replace your she-bang with `#!/usr/bin/env ksh` for example. But that has it's own pitfalls as well, so you might need to research that a bit.

Comment: The basic issue that even `env` is placed in `/usr/bin` and `/bin` in Solaris and Linux respectively fails this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solaris, `/bin` links to `/usr/bin`. Hence the shebang can be changed to `/bin/ksh` to work in both the OS

Answer (score 0):

You can not do a selective shell in the way that you want, i.e., `if` - `then` construct won't work for the shell directive on the *first* line.

Best way as you have mentioned is to create symbolic links to your existing shells. Or, you need to go through each script and replace the '/usr/sbin' string with '/bin' only on the first line of the script, if the first line starts with "#!". It shouldn't be too hard to write a piece of code to go through all your scripts and modify the shell directive fr you.

Comment: But then, how does the same script work in Solaris? I need them to work in both the OS.